# What does | mean?

Tags: command-line, ssh

I have seen this " | " in some commands on the Linux shell but I don't know what it means in general. 
For example, when I run jobs on a shared cluster which uses PBS job scheduler, I can check where the job running is with this command:

```
qstat -j <jobid> | grep cwd
```

I want to know the more general meaning of | so I can apply it elsewhere when it's applicable, instead of just learning by heart the commands when I see others using it.

Thank you in advance. :)

Answer (score 5):

This is not Ubuntu specific, but more a general Linux question, however...

The | symbol is what's known as a pipe. It allows you to "pipe" the output of one command into another. For example:

```
ls | grep foo
```

This will list the files (ls) then send the output to grep to eliminate all content not matching foo

Check out [Piping in Unix or Linux](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/piping-in-unix-or-linux/) for more detailed information.